# How to put data to array and search by specifically row?

Tags: php, arrays

I query from mytable like this.

[image]

I want to put it in array(PHP) and search like this

```
$index = 15;
$result = array_search(...)..);   <--- age_range
```

and put that row ($result) to new array i created;
Or somebody hav better idea.
Sorry some stupid question. Thank for help.

query

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(2 * FLOOR(age / 2), '-', 2 * FLOOR(age / 2) + 5) AS 'age_range',
  SUM(gload1) AS 'g1',
  SUM(gload2) AS 'g2',
  SUM(gload3) AS 'g3',
  SUM(gload4) AS 'g4',
  SUM(gload5) AS 'g5',
  SUM(gload6) AS 'g6',
  SUM(gload7) AS 'g7',
  SUM(gload8) AS 'g8',
  SUM(gload9) AS 'g9',
  SUM(gload10) AS 'g10' 
FROM
  member 
GROUP BY 1 
ORDER BY age ;
```

Comment: SELECT CONCAT(2*floor(age/2), '-', 2*floor(age/2) + 5) as 'age_range',sum(gload1) as 'g1',sum(gload2) as 'g2',sum(gload3) as 'g3',sum(gload4) as 'g4',sum(gload5) as 'g5',sum(gload6) as 'g6',sum(gload7) as 'g7',sum(gload8) as 'g8',sum(gload9) as 'g9',sum(gload10) as 'g10' FROM member GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY age;

Comment: You'd be better editing the question and putting it there, arranged neatly so easy to read :)

Comment: What are you using to access your table? Can you post php source you already have that opens database, and runs query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

Option one - Select all rows from table and then search on the PHP level:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `mytable`;");
$arrayForAllRows = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    array_push($arrayForAllRows,$row);
}
echo array_search("34-36",$arrayForAllRows);
```

(Not tested)

Option two - Get the right data at the first place (mysql):

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `age_range`='34-36'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // Do somthing with each row..
}
```

Comment: Please adjust for `mysqli`!

Answer (score 1):

If you really need **all** that information readily available, you can place it into an readable associate array as you iterate it.

```
$result = mysqli_query( "SELECT.. " ); 

$x = 1;
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) {
    $Label = "g". $x ."";
    $Ages[$row["age_range"]] = array( $Label => $row["g". $x++ .""] );
}

print_r( $Ages );

/**
 * Expected Result:
**/
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [14-16] => Array 
        (
             [g1] => 3102
             [g2] => 5305
             [g3] => 4104
             [g4] => 1909
             [g5] => 7428
             [g6] => 12500
        )
    )

 //Various array functions to search for a value,
 //in_array, array_search etc.
```

But it would be **Much** better retrieving only what you need, although that's not always the case.